# Laravel view shows on chrome dev-tools instead of redirecting to blade

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firebase, laravel-5

Good Day stackoverflow-Devs,

I'm working on a campaign project, where by you can create, edit & view your campaign before you publish it. I'm using MySQL and Firebase Real-time Database to store data. I wrote a JavaScript for-loop and inside there's a if statement with an ajax call to post the data to a laravel controller where by the controller just passes that data to a view.

I have tried using the following view methods:

```
 return view('view-campaign')->with('img',$img); //This one used to work perfectly
```

and:

```
 return redirect('view-campaign')->with('img',$img);
```

and lastly:

```
 return view('view-campaign', ['img',$img]);
```

Here is my Source Code:

## Button

```
<td>
                                        <a onclick="viewCampaign('{{$item->id}}')" class="btn btn-success mb-2"
                                           data-toggle="tooltip" title="view campaign">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> 
                                        </a>
                                  </td>
```

## Javascript-Function

```
function viewCampaign(id){
        console.log(id);
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "apiKey",
            authDomain: "authDomain",
            databaseURL: "databaseURL",
            projectId: "projectId",
            storageBucket: "storageBucket",
            messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
            appId: "appId"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        database = firebase.database();
        var ref = database.ref("CampaignCollection");

        //retrieve firebase stored data
        ref.on('value', function getData(data){
            var obj = data.val();
            var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        
            for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var k = keys[i];
                var F_id = obj[k].id;
                var img = obj[k].Poster;
                var name = obj[k].Name;

                if(id == F_id){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/viewCampaign",
                        data: {
                            'img': img,
                            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        },
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

## view-campaign route

```
  Route::post('viewCampaign','CampaignController@viewCampaign');
```

## view-campaign Controller

```
public function viewCampaign(){

        $img = $_POST['img'];

        return view('view-campaign')->with('img',$img);
              
    }
```

## Response

[image]

The Expected out is to redirect the outcome to a blade and appear as web-page not as a dev-tool response.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is send an ajax request to a normal web route. It will return a web page. So that web page will be returned as the ajax response. You may need to submit the details as a form request.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate a bit feather if you may.

Comment: What you are doing is sending a POST request to /viewCampaign. And In your controller, you are sending an HTML page as response. Ajax request send aynchronous http request to the server and receive data as JSON or XML. Even if you send an HTML page it will be received as raw html and will not be rendered in the browser.

Comment: so is there a way around this issue

Comment: What you can do is, instead of making an ajax request, make a normal form submission to the specified URL

Comment: I tried that but i could find a way to iterate through the data stored on firebase in the controller hence i reverted back to JavaScript.